# Is there any reason to prefer functional programming for data mining projects?

Tags: java, programming-languages, functional-programming, clojure, data-mining

I am researching the possibility of starting a data mining project which will include intensive calculations and transformation on data, and should be relatively easy to scale.

In your experience, is the choice of programming language critical for said project?

For example, if I am already working on a JVM environment, should I prefer Clojure over plain Java? Does the functional environment guarantee easier scalability? Better performance?

Put aside other factors such as familiarity with the language, toolchain, etc. In your experience, is the choice of language a critical one?

Comment: The factors you "put aside" *are* critical. If you start learning Clojure just for this project, you'll either fail to apply its strength - in which case you could just stick with e.g. Java - or lose so much time that it would have to be really awesome for this task to compensate for the lost time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few good reasons for choosing functional programming for data mining projects.

1. Usually data mining projects
   involve algorithmics and mathematics
   (than other types of systems) which
   can be more easily expressed in
   functional programming
2. Data
   mining projects would involve
   aggregate functions - which are better in functional
   programming, say Clojure
3. Data
   mining programs also would be more
   suitable to parallelism - definitely
   data parallelism and could even be
   task parallelism, again a forte of
   functional programming
4. And
   functional languages like Clojure
   can interface with java anyway for I/O, file read and write
5. I
   think one can learn the tool chain
   easily; it is not that different and so that shouldn't be a factor.

I was asking the same question myself and came with a big Yes for Clojure - am still thinking through how to include R in the mix.

Comment: Plus, data mining operations can be seen as a chain of data transformations, something which functional programming languages are very good at.

Comment: Look at Incanter its like R but in Clojure.

Answer (score 3):

Use the most powerful language you are comfortable with.

In any case, if you want to get scalability you need to have a map-reduce implementation which allow you to parallellize and collect the results.

Answer (score 2):

No particular reason. Pick whatever language you feel most comfortable with.

See my answer to a [similar question about natural language processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886913/latest-good-languages-and-books-for-natural-language-processing-the-basics/3898718#3898718). I think that some of the features people think obscure languages are suited to AI are really counterproductive.

Comment: "I think that some of the features people think obscure languages are suited to AI are really counterproductive." << Can you please elaborate on this, preferably with examples?

Comment: @missingfaktor: See the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Often, functional programming solutions are more scalable.

Comment: Even more often, they are not.